# How can I send data from database to client with webservice C#

Tags: c#, wpf, database, web-services

I make a client program. It gets it data from local database and i create a Webservice which
updates data from server to client database.

My question is about how can I send Image(jpg) files from server to client. Can I help do it with webservice.

P.S Database Only saves image file path. I must send files from server to client.

My client program and webservice  written in C# (MS visual Studio)

Database is MS SQl server 2008
Client database is MS Compact Edition

Comment: where is the code ? write something , if there are errors post them !!!

Comment: There is no code for sending image.I want to know how i can do it?

Comment: You you say client, do you mean web browser?

Comment: No ,  client program written in C#  WPF appication which uses SQL Compact edition.

Comment: There are many tutorials how to download file using webservice. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/FILE_DOWNLOAD.aspx) is one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can load the image up into a byte array and send that through the web method. The webmethod just has to have a return type of byte[]

it might be even easier though to skip the webservice for the image though and load it directly from at site - so have a website that is pointed at your image directory. Create a url that references that image - and return that. The client can then do a web request to get that and display it / what whatever it is going to do?